# Call parent method from child method using various argument list

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, argument-passing, method-call

Suppose following situation. There are class hierarchy, that uses various arguments list in a method, that might be extended for each descendant class.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

class A {
    public function __invoke(){
        $arguments = implode(', ', func_get_args());

        echo __METHOD__, ' arguments: ', $arguments, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __invoke(){
        //               ... some actions ...
        // call to parent method with current argument list
        //               ... some actions ...
    }
}
?>
```

If this class hierarhy were implemented with fixed arguments of `__invoke()` method, then I might use something like `parent::__invoke($a, $b, $c, $etc);` to achieve my purpose. But, unfortunately both classes `A` and `B` has some functionality, that relies on various argument lists.

**Now, the question:** *How can I call `parent::__invoke()` from `B::__invoke()` and pass it's arguments list?*

And, yeah, I'll make it more complex: I can not rely on actual name of parent class, because chain might be extended further.

**P.S.:** I just want to mention this somewhere, because this thing is nearly saved my life today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement that, one of which is obvious to me: *to use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/reflection)*.

1. Create a [`ReflectionClass`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php) from class `A`;
2. Get reflection nearest parent with [`ReflectionClass::getParentClass()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php) method;
3. Get `__invoke()` method reflection of parent class by [`ReflectionClass::getMethod()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethod.php) method;
4. Use [`ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php) method to call parent method with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func-get-args) function to pass current argument list.

However, I'm thinking, that it might be an overkill (!) to use this functionality to make a single function call. So I'm considered another way: *old and mighty [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call-user-func-array) function with [`get_parent_class()`](http://php.net/get-parent-class) function*.

1. Get parent class with [`get_parent_class()`](http://php.net/get-parent-class) function;
2. Get current method name (I was thinking to use `__METHOD__` constant, but it always showing a class prefix, where method is declared) with `__FUNCTION__` constant;
3. Call [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call-user-func-array) with method map and pass [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func-get-args) as the second argument.

---

***Solution:***

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

class A {
    public function __invoke(){
        $arguments = implode(', ', func_get_args());

        echo __METHOD__, ' arguments: ', $arguments, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function __invoke(){
        echo __METHOD__, ' actions', PHP_EOL;

        $method = array(get_parent_class($this), __FUNCTION__);
        $result = call_user_func_array($method, func_get_args());

        echo __METHOD__, ' actions', PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$test = new B();

$test(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

***Result:***

```
B::__invoke actions
A::__invoke arguments: 1, 2, 3
B::__invoke actions
```